# Excel - Search for specific words in string and extract text block up to specific character

Tags: excel, excel-formula, text-extraction

I have data in a column of university credentials. I essentially need to search through credentials to find doctorate level or equivalent degrees and extract the text block including the degree and university up to a specific character. At this point I have a nicely working formula that is able to do this well for one input degree only.

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("Ph.D",A1)+1),SEARCH(")",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("Ph.D",A1)+1))-1)
```

So, for example, if I want to find Ph.D. in a text string and extract that block up to the end of the university, it functions as follows:

| RawUniverities | ParsedDoctoralLevel using formula |
| --- | --- |
| B.Sc. (Hons.)(Western Ontario), Ph.D.(British Columbia), LLM (Regina) | Ph.D.(British Columbia |
| B.A.(Simon Fraser), M.A.(Victoria), DPsych (British Columbia), MD (Oxford) |  |
| B.Sc.(Trent), M.Sc.(Alberta), D.Phil.(Western) |  |
| B.Sc.(Hons.) (Guelph),Ph.D (Queen's), MD(Toronto) | Ph.D (Queen's |

The issue I'm having is I need to search for multiple different doctoral level degrees and then extract the block of text in the same manner with the degree and university. So, for this table example, the formula would need to search for Ph.D, MD, DPsych, and D.Phil, to capture everything. In instances where there are two degrees in the list, taking the leftmost would suffice.

An additional note, I have tried to solve this using the following formula, in theory it works but it spills over into the multiple columns, which just does not work for the parsing I'm doing.

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH({"Ph.D","MD","DPsych","D.Phil"},A1)+1),SEARCH(")",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH({"Ph.D","MD","DPsych","D.Phil"},A1)+1))-1)
```

Wondering if anyone can help with a streamlined solution to this. I've hit the limits of my capabilities in excel with this and deep dives online have brought up very little.

It might be worth noting that the list of degrees that will need to be search could be upwards of 50 long. Not sure if the influences a best solution for this?

Edits: adding data to the table, having formatting issues.

Additional raw university test data if interested:

```
B.A.(Winnipeg Bible College), M.A.(London Bible College) M.A., Ph.D.(Toronto) 
B.Com.(Hons.), Ph.D.(British Columbia) 
B.Sc.(Birmingham), M.A.(Toronto), Ph.D.(London) 
B.A. (Hons.)(Queen's), M.A.Sc. (Waterloo), Ph.D. (Queen's) 
B.A. (York), M.A. (Western Ontario), Ph.D. (Rice) 
BSc PT, (JUST), PT MSc (NYIT), Ph.D. (McGill)
M.F.A. (Concordia), M.A. (GCU Lahore) 
Ph.D. (Queen's) 
B.Sc. (Queen's), Ph.D.(Toronto) 
B.A.(British Columbia), LL.B.(Queen's). LL.M.(California) 
B.Sc., MD (Ottawa) 
B.A., M.A. (Toronto), Ph.D. (Harvard) 
LL.B.(Toronto), M.Sc., LL.M.(Queen's), D.Phil.(Oxford) 
B.A.(McGill), J.D. (Queen's) 
B.A. (Wilfrid Laurier), M.A. (Queen’s), M.A., Ph.D (Princeton) 
M.Phil.(London), MN(Dalhousie), Ph.D.(Texas) 
B.A. Hons (Wilfrid Laurier), M.A. (McMaster), Ph.D. (York) 
B.Sc., M.Sc. (Isfahan), Ph.D. (Concordia) 
B.A.(Keele) M.A., D.Phil.(Oxon) 
L.S.M., B.A.(Toronto), J.D. (Queen's), LL.M.(Harvard) 
B.A.(R.M.C.) M.A.(McGill) LL.B.(Queen's), LL.M.(London) 
B.Sc., M.Sc., Ph.D. (Eӧtvӧs Loránd University, Budapest) 
B.Sc., Ph.D. (British Columbia) 
B.A., LL.B. (Toronto), S.J.D. (Harvard) 
B.A.(Hons.)(Queen's), D.Phil.(Oxon) 
B.Ac., MD (Argentina) 
BA, MA, Ph.D. (Toronto)
```

Comment: Why not wrapping it with IFERROR and TEXTJOIN to get result in one column? =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH({"Ph.D","MD","DPsych","D.Phil"},A1)+1),SEARCH(")",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH({"Ph.D","MD","DPsych","D.Phil"},A1)+1))-1),"")))

Comment: @user11222393 Oh yes, this works!!! Thank you, I didn't know I could do such a thing to fix the spill. I do get a couple very minor issues where it duplicates the output if it finds two of the degrees in the text string (e.g.: M.D., C.M. (McGill,Ph.D. M.D., C.M. (McGill
), but this is for like 0.5% of the cases, so easily hadled manually with some cleaning.

Comment: Not "fix", but to deal with. Spill is normal and often desired behavior. Also, if you use Office365 might want to take a look at TEXTAFTER and TEXTBEFORE functions. Good luck!